# Stick a div underneath thumbnails + limit the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright. This might sound a little bit complicated. I've got a script which fetches thumbnails from a JSON. It fetches 9 thumbnails and onclick of the #load it fetches 9 more. How can I set the Load more button underneath the thumbnails and how to make it stick to the bottom of them each time you click it? ( I do not want it like it's now, on the side, but right in the middle and underneath them ).

+BONUS question: How can I fixate the thumbnails so they always show up 3 in a row. Since now, when I resize the window they change ( as you can see in the fiddle, there's only 2 per row now ).

```
jsfiddle.net/z6ge55ky/

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="twitch">

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <div id="load">
    <img class="hvr-pulse" src="http://i.imgur.com/KHIYHFz.png?1">
</div>
</div>

    $(function() {
    var i=0;
    var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
    var twitchData;
    $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
        twitchData = json.streams;

        setData()
    });

    function setData(){
        var j = twitchData.length > (i + 9)  ? (i + 9) : twitchData.length;
        for (; i < j; i++) {
            var streamGame = twitchData[i].game;
            var streamThumb = twitchData[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = twitchData[i].channel.name;
            var img = $('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"/>')
            $('#twitch').append(img);
            img.click(function(){
            $('#twitch iframe').remove()
            $('#twitchframe').append( '<iframe frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden; margin-left: 25px; width:400px; height:250px; position: fixed; top: 0; margin-top: 23.55%;" src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe>');
          });
        }
    }       

    $('#load').click(function() {
        setData();
    }); 
});

#twitch {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

#twitch img {
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    margin: 0 auto; 
    cursor: pointer;
}


#load {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: you want more content to be loaded at the botton (those 9 pictures) after hitting that button?

Comment: That script works. I just want the Load More div/image to be located underneath those images/thumbnails. And it should stick under them even when loaded more. @messerbill

Comment: make 2 different divs - the bottom one is the one containing your load button and the top one the one in which the new images are appended

Comment: @messerbill Doesn't work. It has to go down at the same time the images go down.

Comment: please update your code with the changes

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the width for `#twitch 60%` remove that and for `#load` use `top:100%`

DEMO on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xandershk27/pfcbvm7o/1/)

Comment: Okay, the Load more thing is fixed now. But the thumbnails still change their position on browser window change. Try resizing the fiddle you made and you'll see how there's three in a row and once you make it bigger, there's 4 in a row. @Xander

Comment: if you are using bootstrap framework. please use column and row concept. if not that give width in percentage. so it can be responsive too.

Comment: I have no idea how to apply the Bootstrap rows/columbs to objects which are being parsed from a json.